# jQuery: Horizontally center absolutely position objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to horizontally center a series of objects with a combination of CSS and jQuery. The jQuery part is what I'm having trouble with. Here is my code:

```
$('.tooltip').each(function() {
        $(this).css('margin-left', 0 - ($(this).width / 2) );
}
```

The code above should apply a negative margin-left that is exactly half of the objects width. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Drop the zero, and with is a function !

Comment: Oh, cool. How would that look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.tooltip').each(function() {
        $(this).css('margin-left', '-'+($(this).width() / 2)+'px');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.tooltip {
   position: absolute; 
   width: 300px; // suppose
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -150px; // half of the width
}
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('.tooltip').each(function() {
        $(this).css('margin-left', '-' + $(this).width / 2 + 'px');
}
```

Comment: @colindunnn so lets try the jquery solution